# R: Long-data: how to remove all following obs within same ID once condition is met?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have long data looking like this for example:

```
ID   time   condition
1    1       0
1    2       0
1    3       0
1    4       1
2    1       0 
2    2       1
2    3       1
2    4       0
3    1       1
3    2       1
3    3       0
3    4       0
4    1       0
4    2       1 
4    3       NA
4    4       NA
```

I want to only keep those rows before condition is met once so I want:

```
ID   time   condition
1    1       0
1    2       0
1    3       0
1    4       1
2    1       0 
2    2       1
3    1       1
4    1       0
4    2       1
```

I tried to loop but a) it said looping is not good coding style in R and b) it won't work. 
Sidenote: just if you are wondering, it does make sense that IDs have condition and then lose it again in my example, but I am only interested in when they first had it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy way with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= which.max(condition) | sum(condition) == 0)
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups:   ID [3]
#      ID  time condition
#   <int> <int>     <int>
# 1     1     1         0
# 2     1     2         0
# 3     1     3         0
# 4     1     4         1
# 5     2     1         0
# 6     2     2         1
# 7     3     1         1
```

It relies on `which.max` which returns the index of the *first* maximum value in vector. The `| sum(condition) == 0` takes care to keep censored cases (where condition is always 0).

Using this data:

```
1    1       0
1    2       0
1    3       0
1    4       1
2    1       0 
2    2       1
2    3       1
2    4       0
3    1       1
3    2       1
3    3       0
3    4       0')
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! After at first I did some mistakes it worked for me. I mistakenly typed: 

    filter(row_number() <= which.max(df$condition) | sum(df$condition) == 0)

Instead of 


    filter(row_number() <= which.max(condition) | sum(condition) == 0)

That is a crucial difference! Thank you!

Comment: Gregor, do you have any idea how I can set all subsequent conditions to NA once the condition became 1? So instead of deleting all subsequent observations within the same ID once its 1 set their value of condition to NA. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, but it's different enough you should probably ask a new question. Something with an `ifelse` and lagged `cumsum` perhaps...